# application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is not executed (maybe Mountain Lion issue?)

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I have an iPhone-app that was in appstore for some month (from Nov.2011 until now). On July, 17th I passed an update to itunes and today they rejected it. They sayed it displayes only a black screen when running on an iPad. I tested it, and really, the splash-screen-picture showes up and after few seconds it is replaced not by the apps 1st screen, but by a black screen. (iPad-Simulator as well as physical iPad). But there was no message in Xcodes console.

So, I started the app on my iPhone where I loaded it before July 17th and where I did test the app before releasing: It did run perfectly.

Then I did start it from Xcode on the iPhone-Simulator: Splash-Picture, then black screen but no message in console.

So I connected my iPhone and loaded the newly compiled Version to my iPhone: Black screen!!!

To find out more, I inserted this line into my code at several places in main.m and in appDelegate.m:

```
NSLog(@"%s Line %d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
```

---

Content of main.m:

```
//(some comment-lines)
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSLog(@"%s Line %d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__); //this is line 13
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%s Line %d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__); //this is line 15
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    NSLog(@"%s Line %d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__); //this is line 17
    [pool release];
    NSLog(@"%s Line %d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__); //this is line 19
    return retVal;
}
```

---

I also entered this line in appDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"%s Line %d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
    // some more code
}
```

---

When I run the app, there are only those two lines displayed in Xcodes console:

```
2012-07-28 11:03:29.548 nulowi[4072:c07] int main(int, char **) Line 13
2012-07-28 11:03:29.553 nulowi[4072:c07] int main(int, char **) Line 15
```

So it looks, as if main in main.m was executed and the Autoreleasepool was created. But then, after calling UIApplicationMain in main.m and before calling application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in the apps delegate, there must happened something, and I don't know what this could be.

Maybe it has something to do with the upgrade from Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) to OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) on my MacBook Pro? When I released the ready-tested app on July 17th from my MacBook with version 10.7, everything was fine. Yesterday I installed the update from 10.7 to 10.8.

And now, when trying to run from version 10.8, application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

Would you try to make a complete clean of your project, down to deleting the content of your build folder? Then rebuilding and see what happens...

There could be some issues with what you mention, but only in the sense that something got "mixed-up" between versions of OS/Xcode...

You can find the location of your build files in Xcode preferences (see picture).

[image]

If that does not work, try and change the way UIApplicationMain is called to this:

```
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

specifying the real name for your app delegate.

Comment: I did: in Xcode: Clean (shift-cmd-K). Then I quitted Xcode. I shot down my MacBook. I did switch it on after some seconds, waited 1 minute (just to be shure) and started Xcode. I opened my app, did a Clean again (also just to be shure) and then started the app on the iPhone-Simulator: Splash screen popped up and disappeared after 2 seconds, leaving a black screen. Console-log showed the same two lines (just with a different timestamp). The app's delegate was not called! - So please, where is the build folder that you wanted to be deleted?

Comment: I regret to hear that... I added a snapshot of where you can find out where your build files are; hope you have some luck.

Comment: I tried out anything you proposed. Nothing did help. So I created a new app from scratch and inserted the old sourcecode file-by-file into the new app. On that occasion I adopted the code to ARC. Then I did compile it and it did run perfectly without any error. Only one thing was different: The basic view of a viewcontroller did have a white background before. In the new version it was black. I had to set this views background color explicitely to white which was not necessary in the old version.

Comment: rewriting UIApplicationMain fixed a similar issue for me.